# Inlet valve on dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

My dishwasher is not letting in any water. I think it could be the inlet valve. I've emailed the manufacturer and they are out of stock and do not know when they will be back in. Could just buy any inlet valve or will I need a certain type?

Thanks.

Comment: Make/model of dishwasher?

Comment: There's virtually no appliance or machine in existence where you can use "any" replacement part. Please revise to ask something more specific, and provide enough detail so we can help. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Answer (score 1):

Search online for your make and model - replacement parts.  There are many [appliance parts houses](https://www.repairclinic.com/) (not an endorsement) that also walk you through troubleshooting and/or provide parts diagrams, and ship overnight.